# Why does my son's food/milk intake drop to 1/3 of usual at his grandparents' place?

Tags: toddler, feeding, milk

Every week we stay over at my parents' place for three nights and for some reason my one-year-old son's food and milk intake drops to 1/3 of his usual. We use the same bottles, same milk powder, same food prep, same schedule in the day but for some reason, he refuses to eat nor drink. We thought of so many possibilities but can't get around one issue. He is a dream feeder and even when he is sleeping he refuses to drink. However, the moment we go back home he chugs down his milk and eats as he has been in starvation.

He loves to eat and drinks a decent amount otherwise, we just can't figure this one out. It's been two months now, can anyone can help?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site.  Have you talked to your pediatrician about this?  What did they say?  Also, does your son have any allergy symptoms when at your parents' place?  Is it different in any meaningful way that could cause allergies (which then can make things taste/smell differently)?  Smoke, cats, etc.?

Comment: Can you exclude other food  sources - like a grandparent slipping him snacks without your knowledge?

Comment: Is it warmer, or colder, there?

Comment: It's possible he's just more comfortable at home. Some babies are like that. My 14 month grandson, who also LOVES his bottle and chugs it down, refuses his bottle when at the babysitter's. If he eats and drinks normally at home, I wouldn't worry about it too much, unless you have an extended stay at Grandma and Grandpa. Then you might try a sippy cup, or something new that he doesn't associate with home. Good luck!

Comment: If your baby isn't dropping off his growth curve, specifically weight, and is otherwise normal, then whatever the cause, it's not a problem. Please confirm with your pediatrician, as @Joe suggested.

Comment: I had this with my daughter too. refused to eat in front of anyone she didn't see regularly (ie daily), even family members. It was a PITA because she was underweight for allergy reasons (like 10th percentile). She's 2.5 now and has slowly grown out of it over time. finally!

Answer (score 4):

Obviously very hard to pinpoint the problem without being there to run some tests, but I had a thought. If you're using tap water to make the bottle and his grandparents live in a different neighborhood than you do, it's possible that the water tastes different there and maybe even hurts his stomach. Even though you add milk powder, the different taste of the water can still be noticeable. Try to make the bottle using spring water or water from your own home and see if it makes the difference. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like a change of environment, kids' diet and habits are impacted by surrounding. It could be temperature, number of people, other food options, noise, or lights. You need to simulate his actions and find out what he might like to eat otherwise. It should be his sleep due to a change in bed too that can impact his diet.

Hope this helps.